# How to avoid a list to iterate when there are zero element

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I was searching  for a solution when a list has a zero elements and avoid to iterate in `stream().filter()` lambda function, like:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
list.stream().filter(element -> element.getProperty().equals("bla").findFirst().get();
```

Then the program throws a `NullPointerException` if the list has a zero size, but it wasn't null.

So I used a traditional solution to check if the **list** was **empty** like:

```
if(list.size()> 0 ) 
  list.stream.filter( .....
```

Do you know a different solution without using traditional if check?

**Update**

Sorry for the report the exception, actually, the exception was a

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

Instead of a `NullPointerExcption`.

**Update 2**

So as the VGR said, I will improve the code

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
list.stream().filter(element -> element.getName().equals("bla").findFirst().get();
```

And the class Person :

```
public class Person { 
    String name;
    public getName(){ 
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming the stream itself checks if it's empty before doing any major processing....

Comment: That is not true.  Calling `stream()` on an empty list will cause the Stream to never invoke its filter and findFirst() will always return an empty Optional.  You should not check the size at all.  Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates how an empty list can generate a NullPointerException.

Comment: Sorry , the program launch a **java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present**
I updated the original question.

Comment: You are calling .get() on an optional that is empty.....

Comment: Your question is a bit confused still. [A Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would really help. Run it yourself first so you know for sure it’s compilable and reproducible, please.

Comment: NPE in your first block of code can occur if `element` or `element.getProperty()` could be `null`. On the other hand, the NSEE in the second block could only occur is the stream after the `filter` has no more elements and results in `Optional.empty` for the terminal operation `findFirst`.

Comment: `java.util.NoSuchElementException` means that you are `get`ting the value of an empty optional! Have a look at Andronicus' answer...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Optional#ifPresent`:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(element -> element.getProperty().equals("bla"))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(/** process element if exists */);
```

Comment: So the exception continues, spite of the exception launch is a kind of stackoverflow error.

Comment: @alexandremonassaMoreira null pointer must appear in the filter clause then

Comment: The method ifPresent() is good for some reasons, but for me the best solution is the method orElse() or  orElseGet(); thanks for your help;

Comment: @alexandremonassaMoreira no problem, consider marking the answer as correct;>

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by doing a `orElseGet()`.